# Can I detect if the touchkeyboard is currently deployed and request it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, windows-10, virtual-keyboard

On windows 10, the touch keyboard can be automatically deployed when the user presses on a text-input field. This is quite inconsistent in chrome.

I was wondering, if a Chrome extension could

- Detect if the keyboard was currently deployed
- Request the touch keyboard on demand

If those things are not possible, would a solution be to use a Chrome extension together with a Native windows application via Native Messaging? Would a native Windows application be able to detect and request the touchkeyboard, without stealing focus off the input-field in Chrome?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the [`key`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/keyboardevent-keys-codes) attribute which was presented in the documentation. To check the `code` attribute, visit the [specification field](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#code-virtual-keyboards). "*The code value should be the key value generated when the button is pressed while the device is in its factory-reset state.*"